# Spring @Async @Autowired null in only one method

Tags: spring, multithreading, asynchronous, autowired

I am encountering a NullPointerException in my Spring application when calling a method on an autowired object. The class in question looks like the following:

```
@Component
public class Listener {

  @Autowired
  TemplateService templateService;

  @Async
  @EventListener
  private Future<String> listener1(Event1 event) {
    System.out.println(templateService);
    return new AsyncResult<>(null);
  }

  @Async
  @EventListener
  public Future<String> listener2(Event2 event) {
    System.out.println(templateService);
    return new AsyncResult<>(null);
  }
}
```

When I publish an event that triggers `listener1`, a `null` value is printed, but when I publish an event that triggers `listener2`, the `toString()` method of `TemplateService` is called (as I would expect). I'm probably misunderstanding some aspect of how `@Async` affects `@Autowired` objects, but I haven't been able to determine what that would be. Am I misusing `@Async`? Am I misunderstanding how to use `@Autowired` objects in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: Your class doesn't implement an interface, which means it can't be considered for classpath scanning. You're not misusing Async.

Comment: @JamesENL I'm not sure what you mean by that. The templateService is wired in listener2, so the Spring context must be aware of the class. What interface would I be implementing?

Comment: Your listener doesn't have an interface on it, so Spring isn't aware of it as a class, nor can it create a proxy to use to create the Async methods.

Comment: @JamesENL I really don't know what you mean by that. Are you saying that Spring can only be aware of classes that implement **any** interface?

Comment: By default yes (there are ways around it, but that's not relevant), you need to have an interface, that should define listener1 and listener2 which this class should implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the visibility of your listener1 method to be at least protected (package visibility , protected or public). This is because Spring creates a proxy which is  a subclass of your component. It overrides your @Async annotated methods in order to add new logic to execute your code in a separate thread. However because it uses inheritance it can only override methods which are visible to the subclass.

This explains why listener2 method which is public works.

Change your method to

```
@Async
  @EventListener
  public Future<String> listener1(Event1 event) {
    System.out.println(templateService);
    return new AsyncResult<>(null);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring needs an interface to create a proxy class. It's this proxy class that gets called every time you call the method, and it's through this method that the whole asynchronous execution happens. Without an interface Spring can't autowire, scan or make methods execute asynchronously.

```
public interface Listener { 

    public Future<String> listener1(Event1 event);
    public Future<String> listener2(Event2 event);
}

@Component
public class ListenerImpl { 

    @Autowired
    private TemplateService templateService;

    @Async
    @Override
    public Future<String> listener1(Event1 event) {
        System.out.println(templateService);
        return new AsyncResult<>(null);
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public Future<String> listener2(Event2 event) {
        System.out.println(templateService);
        return new AsyncResult<>(null);
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that Spring can't run private methods asynchronously.

Comment: Its not required that a component has to implement an interface so that Spring can proxy it. Its a recommended practice but Spring can still use CGLIB class based proxies if a component does not implement at least one interface. However you are spot on in terms of method visibility. The @Async method has to be visible to subsclasses so that Spring can override it in the proxy class. To intercept your method in order to run in a separate thread Spring has to override your method to weave in the new behavior